# What is the stance on spoilers around here?

Tags: discussion

I am somewhat new around here. I recently answered a question [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/98800/46178) that had me wondering if I was supposed to hide parts of it behind spoiler tags and if so what formatting is avalible if any to hide parts of my answer.

Comment: in this case, I might have put some of that behind a spoiler, but it's probably old enough now that you won't get too much grief for it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried finding that info but failed. The only reason that I would put that behind spoiler tags is that it is a season end episode and doctor change episode.